# C++11 устарел или сгодится для начинающих?

Tags: c++

Начал учить С++.Взял книгу по С++11. Пишут, что при использовании using для пространства имен нужно прописывать std для каждой команды, для cin отдельно, для cout отдельно и т.д. Хотя в реальности достаточно один раз указать using std и спокойно пользоваться командами. Отсюда вопрос: С++11 устарел или таких анахронизмов очень мало? Есть ли смысл учить по литературе С++11? Путь не близкий, хотелось бы на старте пойти верным путем.

Comment: всё устарело, начиная с машины тьюринга и фон-неймановской архитектуры.

Comment: *"в реальности достаточно один раз указать using std и спокойно пользоваться командами"* - нет, `using std` делает не то, что вы думаете, что оно делает. Так что никогда так не делайте. При чем тут С++11 - совершенно непонятно. При изучении С++ придется разбираться со всеми вариантами языка, начиная с "С c классами".

Comment: Или написали ерунду, или вы прочитали (поняли) ерунду... Кстати, обратная совместимость вполне действует.

Comment: зы поясню: `using std` кажется был еще в бородатые времена до С++03 и страдал от тех же проблем

Comment: Рекомендации "используйте using для каждой команды", "не используйте using в заголовочных файлах", "предпочитайте использовать полностью квалифицированные имена, вместо использования  using" и т.д. в равной мере актуальны для всех версий, от C++98 до ,будущего C++2x.

Comment: Почитайте про пространство имен. Такое есть и в других языках.

Comment: Странно, что вопрос так резко минусуют, тут же не клянчат решения для учебных задач, а заковырки в поиске имен и работе using std - это далеко не тривиальная тема.

Comment: Да, книги по С++11 подойдут. Главное чтобы не старее. Но то, по что вы пишете, не менялось после С++11.